# heroku DATABASE_URL

Tags: heroku

On heroku, how to get the whole value of DATABASE_URL ?

When I issue a

```
heroku config --app APP_NAME
```

I get several config parameters but the DATABASE_URL is not entirely visible

```
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://ruhej...s.com/oeuhenchej
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$ heroku config --app APP_NAME
```

*(The Heroku toolbelt has been updated since the question was asked; the command now shows the entire `DATABASE_URL`.)*

Comment: @Clément I think the --long option has been removed? In the heroku toolbelt v2.28.15 I don't have it, but simply running 'heroku config' shows the entire value for all of my config vars.

Comment: `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app APP_NAME` for just the url

Answer (score 5):

```
$ heroku pg:credentials:url YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
```

Gives you all the informations needed (url, port, dbname, user, password):

```
Connection information for default credential.
Connection info string:
   "dbname=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx host=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=zzzzzzzzzzzzzz password=************* sslmode=require"
Connection URL:
   postgres://zzzzzzzzzzzzzz:*************@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem really basic but your heroku APP_NAME is app_name.heroku.com.  You can find that by logging into heroku.com and looking in your account.  In order to get your app config variables you simply type into the console:

```
heroku config --app APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full database URL, use `config:get` from the Heroku CLI;

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

***To get PostgreSQL dump file from heroku :-***

`heroku pg:backups:capture`

`heroku pg:backups`
it shows all the backups

`heroku pg:backups:url BackupID`